# Wanted to make server on Apache Cordova

Tags: database, server, visual-studio-cordova, connectivity

i wanted to make an app for my college with apache cordova in visual studio 2015. For this i need my app to connect with database and make a server. PHP is not going to run on this software. i want coding for my app, if anybody could help please. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You will create web service or rest service on a server to perform your database actions and return json results.  Then the Cordova app will call these services, usually using AJAX.